# Select values that begin with a number in influxDB

Tags: grafana, influxdb

can i have equivalent of below query for influxdb:
`SELECT * FROM Table WHERE YourColumn regexp '^[0-9]+'` (It is a sql server query)

Comment: Yes, https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/query_language/data_exploration/#regular-expressions

Answer (score 0):

Got it `select * from tablename where columnname =~ /[0-9]+/`  to filter all values starts with interger.

Comment: Have you tested if this would not also match something that has digits anywhere in the value ?
Such as `after1` ? I'd expect that if you want to match a digit at the beginning the expression would be `/^[0-9]+/` as it is for sql